# Performance decreases after you move a report that contains a large multi-select drop-down parameter list to SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report which has 15 Parameters and out of 15 params,2 have 1000 list of values.
When i run this report on SQL Server 2008 r2 report server it is taking 2 minutes of time.
I have installed CU 7 as suggested in MS forum but unfortunately it didn't fixed my Problem.
Why CU 7 is not working for me?any idea?help....

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Praveen

---

**Hot fix that installed only works on Windows 7/2008 not on Win XP!!!!!!!
Thanks....**